# How to use dot operator only in struct?

Tags: struct, operator-keyword

Could you modify below codes in order to work ".a, .b" code?
I mean I want to see ".a, .b" working NOT data.a, data.b..

```
typedef ABC_struct {
    int a;
    int b;
}ABC_struct;

ABC_struct   data{
    .a =
    .b =
}
```

Comment: You should specify what language is this. I assume this is C99. In this case your syntax is wrong. Search for designated initializers. I am flagging this as an off-topic as it only contains syntax errors.

Comment: (Assuming C/C++) - the values are in order so you don't need to/can't specify the names so: ABC_struct   data = { a_value, b_value};

Comment: #include <stdio.h>

typedef struct A{
 int i, j;
}A;



A a = { 
 .i = 10,
 .j = 35
   };



int main(){
 printf("%d %d\n", a.i, a.j);
 return 0;
}